# Passing missing argument from function to function in R

Tags: r, arguments, function-calls

I’ve learned that it’s common practice to use optional arguments in function and check them with missing()
(e.g. as discussed in [SO 22024082](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22024082/when-to-using-missing-versus-null-values-for-passing-undefined-function-argument))

In this example round0 is the optional argument (I know, round0 could be defined as logical).

```
foo = function(a, round0) {
    a = a * pi
    if(!missing(round0)) round(a)
    else a
}
```

But what if I call this function from another function, how can I pass “missing”?

```
bar = function(b) {
    if(b > 10) round1=T
    foo(b, round1)
}
```

If b < 10 then round1 in bar() is not defined, but is passed to foo anyway. If I modify foo():

```
foo = function(a, round0) {
    a = a * pi
    print(missing(round0))
    print(round0)
    if(!missing(round0)) round(a)
    else a
}
```

and run bar(9) the output is:

```
bar(9)
[1] FALSE
Error in print(round0) : object 'round1' not found
Called from: print(round0)
```

That means: round0 is not missing, but can’t be accessed either?

I don’t want to use different function calls in bar(), if there are several optional arguments in foo(), I would have to write a function call for every missing/not missing - combination of all optional arguments.

Is it possible to pass "missing", or what other solution would apply for this problem?

Comment: Usually, if you call a function in specific form, you should ensure you have all the parameters. Here I would add a `round1=F` at start of `bar` and update `foo` with `if(!missing(round0) && round0)`. Missing allow you to call `foo(a)` or `foo(a,T/F)`, if you call it with two parameters, the second parameter is not missing and have to be resolvable.

Comment: My guess is that `missing` returns `FALSE` as soon as the promise object that represents the function argument has a non-empty expression slot. Add the line `print(substitute(round0))` right after `a = a * pi` in your modified `foo` function and then execute `foo(9)`. `substitute` will extract the expression slot. It will print nothing, i.e., an empty expression slot for `round0`. Now try `bar(9)`. This prints `round1`. But when you use `print`, R will try to evaluate `round1` which was not defined yet (lazy evaluation).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In your example, round0 isn't missing, it's set to `round1` which is undefined (as opposed to missing).

The best way in general of doing this is to use a default value, in your case `FALSE`:

```
foo = function(a, round0 = FALSE) {
    a = a * pi
    if (!round0) round(a)
    else a
}

bar = function(b) {
    round1 <- FALSE
    if (b > 10) round1=TRUE
    foo(b, round1)
}
```

or where the default value cannot easily be expressed in the parameter list:

```
foo = function(a, round0 = NULL) {
    a = a * pi
    if(!is.null(round0)) round(a)
    else a
}

bar = function(b) {
    round1 <- NULL
    if (b > 10) round1=TRUE
    foo(b, round1)
}
```

Note in both cases you need to set the parameter to be the default value manually in your calling function.

You could also call your `foo` function with or without an argument if needed within your `if` statement:

```
bar = function(b) {
    if (b > 10) foo(b, TRUE) else foo(b)
}
```

An alternative approach that shows how to generate a missing value is shown by @moody_mudskipper’s [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58544714).

Comment: The last statement is inaccurate. You can make a variable missing by defining it as `quote(expr=)`, `substitute()` or `alist(x=1)[[1]]`. The former is the most efficient. {rlang} has a `missing_arg` function that does the same too. See my own answer below.

Comment: @Moody_Mudskipper thanks, I didn’t know that. I’ve modified my answer to point to yours.

Answer (score 8):

I recently encountered a similar problem and wanted to solve it in a general way. I think it can be done as shown in the definition of the function `g()` below:

```
f <- function(a = 5, b = 3, c = 2, d = 7) {
  if (missing(a)) {print("a is missing.")}
  if (missing(b)) {print("b is missing.")}
  if (missing(c)) {print("c is missing.")}
  if (missing(d)) {print("d is missing.")}

  cat(a, b, c, d)
}

g <- function(a = 1, b = 1, c = 1, d = 1) {
  args <- as.list(match.call())
  args[[1]] <- NULL # remove first list element, it's the function call
  do.call(f, args, envir = parent.frame())
}
```

Here is what we get when calling `g()` with different sets of arguments:

```
> g()
[1] "a is missing."
[1] "b is missing."
[1] "c is missing."
[1] "d is missing."
5 3 2 7

> g(a = 3)
[1] "b is missing."
[1] "c is missing."
[1] "d is missing."
3 3 2 7

> g(b = 10, c = 10)
[1] "a is missing."
[1] "d is missing."
5 10 10 7
```

You can add to or remove from the `args` list if you don't want to hand all arguments to the next function or want to add some. As an example, see the following function `g()` that does this in a general way:

```
g <- function(a = 1, b = 1, c = 1, x = 1, y = 1, z = 1) {
  f_args <- c("a", "b", "c") # arguments we want to hand off to function f

  # obtain the list of arguments provided
  args <- as.list(match.call())
  # remove first list element, it's the function call
  args[[1]] <- NULL
  # remove the arguments that are not listed in f_args
  args <- args[na.omit(match(f_args, names(args)))]

  # now add argument d, we always want it to be 0:
  args <- c(args, list(d = 0))
  do.call(f, args, envir = parent.frame())
}
```

Here is what we get when calling `g()` with different sets of arguments:

```
> g()
[1] "a is missing."
[1] "b is missing."
[1] "c is missing."
5 3 2 0

> g(a = 3)
[1] "b is missing."
[1] "c is missing."
3 3 2 0

> g(b = 10, c = 10)
[1] "a is missing."
5 10 10 0
```

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47734499/4975218) for additional information on `do.call()`.

Answer (score 4):

You can create a missing object by using `substitute()` without argument.

In your case we could make `round1` a missing object in the `else` clause :

```r
foo = function(a, round0) {
  a = a * pi
  if(!missing(round0)) round(a)
  else a
}

bar = function(b) {
  if(b > 10) round1=T else round1 <- substitute()
  foo(b, round1)
}

bar(9)
#> [1] 28.27433
```

<sup>Created on 2019-10-24 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Comment: `missing()` needs it's input to be something (its name is an oxymoron in this regard). This something is an empty expression, and it appears `substitute()` can create some, you could also do `alist(x=)[[1]]`. For the long answer we'd need to get into the C implementation and I don't know much about it.

Answer (score 1):

`rlang` provides also a function `missing_arg()` that makes an argument be missing.

```r
foo = function(a, round0) {
  a = a * pi
  if(!missing(round0)) round(a)
  else a
}

bar = function(b) {
  if(b > 10) round1 <- TRUE else round1 <- rlang::missing_arg()
  foo(b, round1)
}

foo(9)
#> [1] 28.27433
bar(9)
#> [1] 28.27433
```

<sup>Created on 2020-12-02 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>