# R Function Doesn't Throw Error As Expected

Tags: r, exception

At end of question is script (plus on [github](https://github.com/ArtieLadie/RanglaPunjab/blob/master/R/RanglaPunjab.R)). The GitHub repo is [here](https://github.com/ArtieLadie/RanglaPunjab) and can be installed with

```
install.packages("devtools")
devtools::install_github("ArtieLadie/RanglaPunjab")
```

`MergePalette(name,name2)` takes two names. If person only passes one name, I want the following to execute and then exit the function,

`Enter 2 valid palettes. Run ListPalette() for list of palettes.`

Unfortunately, when I execute `MergePalette("Teej")`, I get

`Error in MergePalette("Teej") : 
  argument "name2" is missing, with no default`

How to fix this

```
MergePalette <- function(name,name2){

  pal <-  RanglaPunjab(name)

  if (is.null(name2)){
    stop("Enter 2 valid palettes. Run ListPalette() for list of palettes.")
 }
  pal2 <-  RanglaPunjab(name2)

  new_pal <-unique(c(pal,pal2))

  new_pal
}
```

Comment: better post the code of the function directly here

Comment: Link to repo is broken. What is the code that you expect to throw an error?

Comment: I'm assuming https://github.com/ArtieLadie/RanglaPunjab, so edited the question accordingly.

Comment: @Moody_Mudskipper Goodness, I totally forgot. Now I posted code.

Comment: @CalumYou Oh, ok, I posted link to [code](https://github.com/ArtieLadie/RanglaPunjab/blob/master/R/RanglaPunjab.R) on original message

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two methods:

1. **Preferred**: Check for missingness:

   ```
   MergePalette <- function(name,name2){
     if (missing(name2)) { stop(...) }
   ```
2. Define a default value of `NULL` in the formals, and the function works:

   ```
   MergePalette <- function(name,name2=NULL){
     if (is.null(name2)) { stop(...) }
   ```

   If the user (accidentally) provides an argument to `name2` that is itself `NULL`, the error message will be confusing. As @Moody_Mudskipper noted, by setting the default to `NULL`, you are implicitly telling the user that this argument is optional and/or that `NULL` is okay. With that, I suggest that this option is not appropriate for this question/use.

Comment: I don't think "Enter 2 valid palettes" would be a confusing message if the user entered `NULL`. Do you have other reasons to say `missing` is preferred ? I had the feeling it was used often in base R but avoided in favor of default `= NULL` most of the time in important packages.

Comment: Relevant : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22024082/when-to-use-missing-versus-null-values-for-passing-undefined-function-arguments . I believe in this case using missing is appropriate as it feels wrong to give to an argumenr a default value that would make the function return an error. However in other cases setting NULL as default is explicitly telling to users that it's ok to skip this argument.